# Use globbed paths with git?

Tags: git, glob

I use `.sass` files now in a project that used only `.css` files before.

I added `.sass` files with `git add` file by file.

Now I would want to remove all my `.css` files in one command, after added `*.css` and `*.css.map` in my `.gitignore`

Is this command syntaxically valid ?

```
git remove modules/**/*.css
git remove modules/**/*.css.map
```

Comment: I think this depends more on the fact whether bash understands `**` than on git itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try replacing `remove` with `rm`:

```
git rm modules/**/*.css
git rm modules/**/*.css.map
```